# AppEngine with Eclipse - Common war/ resources

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

I have been creating Google AppEngine projects using Eclipse SDK 3.6.1.

In all of the projects I have a StyleSheet default.css (all seperate copies) that I have in the war folder.

I would like to keep this file in one place to be included in all of the projects.

I have created a copy in the workspace folder.

I have tried linking the file into the war folder, it shows up as a linked file, I can edit it, and all looks fine.

When I run the application I can see by the webpage created that it is not recognizing the linked file.

I hope that I am missing something simple, I do not like keeping multiple copies of a common resource.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

RRaney

Answer (score 1):

Creating a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the file will do the job.

For example, on a Windows 7/Vista machine, run a command like this from the shell (as an administrator) to link two folders:

```
mklink /D C:\workspace\YetAnotherAppEngineProject\war\shared C:\workspace\SharedResourcesProject\shared
```

I assume that when you wrote "I have tried linking the file into the war folder" you meant that you tried linking a file/folder into the war folder using Eclipse's linked file/folder functionality. These links are limited to the Eclipse IDE and managed by it (int the .project file) - the Google App Engine runtime doesn't recognize them since it accesses the file system directly and not through Eclipse.

A symbolic link is done at the file-system level, and Google App Engine will recognize and respect it properly.

To create a symbolic link, use the "[ln](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_%28Unix%29)" shell command on Linux. On Windows Vista/7 use "[mklink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)" (earlier Windows versions only have "hard links" which are not as nice for this purpose but should also get the job done, see the "[linkd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)" command).

Comment: if none of those symlink options work for you in windoes you can also install junction from sysinternals, which provides a command line interface for creating symlinks. see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "[Static Files and Resource Files](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files)"?